# If $\sec(t) = a + 1/(4a)$, prove that $\sec(t) + \tan(t) = 2a$ or $1/(2a)$

Tags: trigonometry

I tried to convert $\sec(t)$ into $1/\cos(t)$ and figure out the value for $\sin(t)$. 
Then I tried to figure out $\tan(t)$ with the values I got but I don't seem to be able to get $2a$ or $1/2a$.

What would be the best approach to solve this question?

Comment: What did you get for sin($t$) and tan($t$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$(a+\frac{1}{4a})^2-1=(a-\frac{1}{4a})^2$$

Recall that $\sec^2\theta -1 =\tan^2\theta$

Comment: More succinct version of mine. Faster to enter, too.

Comment: Why I prefer writing hints to full answers. Also makes the OP think.

Comment: Thanks, Rhys. I am reviewing trigonometry and I think I forgot almost everything.

Answer (score 2):

$\sec(t) = a+\dfrac1{4a}$.

Since

$\begin{array}\\
\tan^2(t)+1
&=\dfrac{\sin^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)}+1\\
&=\dfrac{\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(t)}\\
&=\sec^2(t)\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\tan^2(t)
&=\sec^2(t)-1\\
&=(a+\dfrac1{4a})^2-1\\
&=a^2+\dfrac12+\dfrac1{16a^2}-1\\
&=a^2-\dfrac12+\dfrac1{16a^2}\\
&=(a-\dfrac1{4a})^2\\
\text{so}\\
\tan(t)
&=\pm(a-\dfrac1{4a})\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\tan(t)+\sec(t)
=a+\dfrac1{4a}\pm(a-\dfrac1{4a})
=2a
$
or
$\dfrac1{2a}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sec t+\tan t=\lambda$. From the simple Algebraic identity $[x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)]$ and the Pythagorean identity involving secant and tangent functions: $$\sec^2t-\tan^2t=(\sec t+\tan t)(\sec t-\tan t)=1$$ You can rewrite $\sec t-\tan t=\dfrac{1}{\sec t+\tan t}=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$. Summing up the expressions we get: $$\lambda +\dfrac{1}{\lambda}=2\sec t =2a+\dfrac{1}{2a}\implies \lambda=2a \ \text{or} \dfrac{1}{2a} \text{.}$$

Comment: This is my way(+1)

Answer (score 0):

$$(2a)^2-2(2a)\sec t+1=0$$

$$2a=\dfrac{2\sec t\pm\sqrt{(2\sec t)^2-4}}2=\sec t\pm\tan t$$

If $\sec t-\tan t=2a,\sec t+\tan t=\dfrac1{\sec t-\tan t}=?$

Else $\sec t+\tan t=2a$

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the best approach.  See other answers for that.  I just wanted to show that it could be done the way you had tried, using only very basic identities:

$$\frac  1 {\cos t} = \sec t = a + \frac 1 {4a} = {4a^2+1 \over 4a}$$

so

$$\cos t = {4a \over {4a^2+1}}$$

so

$$\cos^2 t = {(4a)^2 \over {(4a^2+1)^2}}$$

so

$$\sin^2 t = 1 - \cos^2 t = {(4a^2+1)^2-(4a)^2 \over (4a^2+1)^2} = {(4a^2-1)^2 \over (4a^2+1)^2}$$

so

$$\sin t = \pm \frac{4a^2-1}{4a^2+1}$$

so $$\tan t = {\frac {\sin t} {\cos t}}= \pm {4a^2-1\over 4a} = \pm (a - {{1} \over{4a}}),$$

from which the expression given  for $\sec t + \tan t$ easily follows.